# Using xlwt to print xls to paper

Tags: python, xlwt

So, I am using the xlwt and xlrd modules in python to write to a XLS document.
What I am trying to do now, is to have this useless file be printed out on paper, old school style, but searching for "print out on paper" (or the like) just gives you the wrong results. Can anyone help me?

here is the code:

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
from tkinter import *


def test():
    print(ent.get())

    rb = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xls")
    wb = copy(rb)
    w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
    w_sheet.write(0,1,ent.get())
    fr = w_sheet.col(0)
    fr.width = 256 * 20
    wb.save("test.xls")

vindue = Tk()

but = Button(vindue, text="Click", command=test)
but.pack()

ent = Entry(vindue)
ent.pack()

vindue.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution my self.

```
import win32api
import win32print

filename = "test.xlsx"
    open(filename, "r")
    win32api.ShellExecute(
        0,
        "print",
        filename,
        '/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter(),
        ".",
        0
    )
```